# Create Tensorflow Dataset from Examples

Tags: tensorflow

I am following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/mostly-ai/tensorflow-records-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them-c46bc4bbb564

and I have created some `SequentialExamples`, how can I create a `tf.data.Dataset` from these?

I have a 1-D Python list of stock market values and want to eventually feed a neural network the values t1,t2,t3 and make it predict t4 and t5. I will call the following method and create many examples, where X is the input and Y the prediction.

```
def make_example(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2]):
  x_feature = [tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=x))]
  y_feature = [tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=y))]

  x_flist = tf.train.FeatureList(feature=x_feature)
  y_flist = tf.train.FeatureList(feature=y_feature) 

  feature_lists = tf.train.FeatureLists(feature_list={
      "input_x": x_flist,
      "output_y": y_flist
  })

  example = tf.train.SequenceExample(feature_lists=feature_lists)
  print(example)
  return example
```

I want to create a `tf.data.Dataset` from a Python list of `tf.train.SequenceExample`.

Comment: Hey jdoe. Try to give a bit more context. Give code exmaples if you already have something. This makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, will update soon.

Comment: @H4kor updated, can you take a look now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open writer

```
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(file_name.tfrecords)
example = tf.train.SequenceExample(feature_lists=f_lists)
writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()
```

Then create parse function

```
def parse_fn(example):
    example_features = {"input_x": x_flist,
                        "output_y": y_flist}
    parsed = tf.parse_single_example(serialized=example, features=example_features)

    return input_x, output_y
```

Then create dataset

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(file_name.tfrecords)
dataset = dataset.shuffle().repeat()
dataset = dataset.map(parse_fn)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets

Comment: So if I want to create a Dataset I always: 1. Create examples in RAM, 2. Store examples in Disk, 3. Read examples from Disk? This sounds inefficient do you know why we are doing it this way?

Comment: Create tfrecord is a one time operation, off course. Depending on your data, it can take time